# Последовательный GUID

Tags: sql, sql-server

Прошу помощи в составлении SQL запроса на получении последовательного GUID поля 'ID', чтобы в дальнейшем его программно передать в запрос на добавления записи

Comment: что значит **последовательный** [GUID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID)?

Comment: Я так понял, это функция `NEWSEQUENTIALID`

Comment: [NEWSEQUENTIALID](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) генерирует GUID, он создается на сервере...

Comment: Мне так и нужно, узнать какой будет следующий GUID и вернуть его результатом. Это возможно?

Comment: зачем Вам знать какой будет следующий идентификатор? а что если приложении многопользовательское, один клиент получил *следующий*, а другой клиент до вставки первым его уже занял?

Comment: Чтобы запросом его уже вставить через код программы

Comment: если Вам так хочется самому, то тогда генерируйте GUID на клиенте\

Comment: GUID на клиенте и на сервере будет разным в диапазоне, мне нужен последовательный GUID только на машине сервера )

Comment: исходя из описания [GUID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID): *вероятность того, что в мире будут независимо сгенерированы два совпадающих ключа, крайне мала*, а ключ должен быть уникальным. что значит **последовательный** в вашем понимании, в моем это 1, 2, 10, я такого про GUID сказать не могу, он будет просто **другим**

Comment: GUID обычно генерируется на стороне сервера (имеется в виду программы)...т е на серверном языке asd.net или php или другом. Зачем вам это делать именно в SQL? Для sql есть [такая](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) статья

Comment: Сейчас вы хотите сперва сгенерировать guid и получить его на клиент для последующей вставки с ним. Поступите ровно наоборот: вставляйте запись в БД с автоматической генерацией guid, а потом получайте его на клиент.

Comment: @Bald - использование последовательного GUID в ряде сценариев существенно выгоднее. https://stackoverflow.com/q/170346/5045688

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov мне не понятно что такое *последовательный guid*

Comment: @Bald - Что любопытно, не нашёл толкового описания sequential guid на русском языке. На английском инфы предостаточно. Задал вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/975240/184217 - ждём-с ответа.

Answer (score 3):

Сейчас вы хотите сперва сгенерировать GUID и получить его на клиент для последующей вставки с ним.

Поступите ровно наоборот: вставляйте запись в БД с автоматической генерацией GUID, а потом получайте его на клиент.

Допустим, таблица создана следующим образом:

```
create table SomeTable
(
    id uniqueidentifier default newsequentialid(),
    foo text
)
```

Запрос на вставку будет таким:

```
insert into SomeTable (foo)
output inserted.id
values ('bar')
```

В коде C# это будет выглядеть так:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"..."))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into SomeTable (foo) output inserted.id values ('bar')";
    conn.Open();
    var guid = (Guid)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    Console.WriteLine(guid);
}
```

PS: Конечно, во избежание sql-инъекций следует всегда использовать параметры. Здесь код без них только ради упрощения восприятия.